# Need suggestion to code for filter icon

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to code in selenium web drive java  for the below code. I am using java eclipse. I am trying to find the element for the Filter menu. Once I click the filter icon filter menu will be displayed. When I try to find element by clicking filter icon using the firebug the below code got highlighted `span class="k-icon k-filter` xpath is also not working.

```
<th class="k-header k-filterable k-with-icon" scope="col" data-title="Package Detail" data-index="0" data-field="PackageDetail.Namee" data-role="columnsorter">
 <a class="k-grid-filter" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">
  <span class="k-icon k-filter"/>
 </a>
 <a class="k-link" href="/Valiadationrule/GetData?ValiadationruleGrid-sort=PackageDetail.Namee-asc">Package Detail</a>
</th>

<th class="k-header k-filterable k-with-icon" scope="col" data-title="Category" data-index="1" data-field="Category" data-role="columnsorter">
 <a class="k-grid-filter" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">
  <span class="k-icon k-filter"/>
</a>
<a class="k-link" href="/Valiadationrule/GetData?ValiadationruleGrid-sort=Category-asc">Category</a>
</th>

<th class="k-header k-filterable k-with-icon" scope="col" data-title="Name" data-index="2" data-field="Name" data-role="columnsorter">
 <a class="k-grid-filter" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">
   <span class="k-icon k-filter"/>
 </a>
 <a class="k-link" href="/Valiadationrule/GetData?ValiadationruleGrid-sort=Name-asc">Name</a>
</th>
```

Comment: Seems like there are multiple `<span class="k-icon k-filter"/>` tags which might be the cause of your problem. Can you please tell, from above, which **Filter icon** you want to locate and/or click?

Comment: I want to use 1st filter Package Details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try either of the below **Java** codes to click on the first filter icon "Package Detail":

```
//a[.='Package Detail']
```

It will select the element with tag `a` and exact innerHTML/text as `Package Detail`.

**OR**

```
//a[contains(@href,'PackageDetail')]
```

It will select the element with tag `a` and the `href` attribute containing text `PackageDetail`.

---

### EDIT

Based on the latest image, I have figured out what the problem was. Actually, the whole grid is inside a frame with id `bodyframe`. Hence, you have to first switch to the frame, before clicking on the filter icon.

**1- Switching to the frame:**

```
driver.switchTo().frame("bodyframe");
```

**2- Clicking on the filter icon:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'PackageDetail')]/preceding-sibling::a")).click();
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//th[@data-title='Package Detail']//span[@class='k-icon k-filter']/..")).click();
```

OR

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//th[@data-title='Package Detail']//span[@class='k-icon k-filter']")).click();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your update but its not working i am getting error message as unable to locate elements

Comment: In that case try either of these xpaths `//th[@data-title='Package Detail']` or `//th[@data-title='Package Detail']//span[@class='k-icon k-filter']`, instead. If it still doesn't work, please [upload a screenshot of the filter using imgur](http://imgur.com/) and add to your question. Need to see how the filter looks, Might become easier to sort this one out then.

Comment: HI still its not working 
http://imgur.com/delete/gjBYZOk8siBbvHU
http://imgur.com/delete/XFlbCeqBv7B3NZk
http://imgur.com/delete/q5hybq4PzIYygT7
http://imgur.com/delete/JKtRo6qRouM4G4e

Comment: Thanks.. From the screenshot, it seems, the above code (in comments), should have worked. Anyways, can you please try either of these xpaths instead: `//a[contains(@href,'PackageDetail')]/preceding-sibling::a` **OR**    `//th[@data-title='Package Detail']//span[@class='k-icon k-filter']/..`

Comment: Okay.. Can you please tell what error/exception are you getting ?

Comment: not working with the above codes please find the image when i select the filter i can see  javascript void()    http://i.imgur.com/DIeK0pX.png

Comment: Yes,.. I am getting that the xpaths above are not working. Can you please tell, **what error/exception are you getting if you run your code using the xpath in the comment above?**  Also, please **check these xpaths in the firepath** too.. See, if it highlights the element that you seek.

Comment: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[contains(@href,'PackageDetail')]/preceding-sibling::a] because of the following error:   Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//th[@data-title='Package Detail']"}    Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//th[@data-title='Package Detail']//span[@class='k-icon k-filter']"}      Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[.='Package Detail']"}  Fire path Xpath=html/body/div[3]/div/section/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/thead/tr/th[1]/a[1]/span

http://i.imgur.com/NbKZYtz.png

Comment: Can you please check my answer above under the **EDIT** header? Hope this helps you out at last.

Comment: SUPER ITS WORKING THANKS A LOT ,i HAVE USED THE FRAME CODE + 1ST CODE IN FILTER ICON

Comment: @irshadmohammedkhan: Phew.. Finally!! Glad it worked out for you,, Please accept this answer so that others who come across similar problems, may refer to this.. :)